# Can't have the "Vox Populi" badge

Tags: support

It's happened twice already (On MartialArts.SE the first time though).

I used all my votes allowance for the day, but the badge tracker indicates me I voted 38 times (Which *might* be true, I don't keep a count :p). The Vox Populi badge asks for 40 votes.

What can I do to receive the badge if I used my full allowance?

Comment: Coincidentally, I upvoted this and the answer as the last 2/40 of my votes for the day. 

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The daily vote limit is a little arcane.  From [this post on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/162102):

> - The exact number of votes available [depends on your voting behavior for the day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90202/). Concretely, there are three upper limits to respect *at the same time* to be able to vote.
>
>   - 40 post votes per day per user.
>   - 30 answer votes per day per user.
>   - 5 post votes after you got your first "5 votes remaining" warning of the day. If you reach 25 answer votes at time `t` of the day, given `q(t)` as the number of question votes cast by time `t`, the total post votes limit will be no more than `30 + q(t)`. If you cast less than 25 answer votes, ignore this point.

So, basically, you get 10 votes *specifically for questions*, but you need to use them early.  Once you get close to the limit of 30 *unrestricted* votes, you can't claim all 10 of the others any more.

No, I don't know why.  I suspect it's a limitation in how voting was implemented (the 10 extra votes for questions were a later addition), rather than an intentional design decision.

Comment: Thank you! At least now I know how to deal with that problem :p

Comment: The 10 votes for questions was to give people extra incentive to vote on questions, often questions are ignored in up voteing