# Why would my vote totals for the day not be adding up?

Tags: support, badges

The *Vox Populi* vote meter says I have cast 34 votes, but I'm being barred from further voting today because I've used all 40. Is this a 24 hours versus UTC thing or what is the reason for this behaviour?

Answer (score 7):

This badge is a bit complicated because you get some votes that you can only use in a certain timeframe and only on questions. This is a feature to encourage people to vote on questions and not only on answers. If you only vote on answers for some days you at some point get a message that should discourage that behaviour a bit and that goes something like

> You haven't voted on questions in a while. Questions need votes, too!

See [here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2792/28789) for more information. I am copying Monicas answer:

> The daily vote limit is a little arcane.  From [this post on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/162102):
>
> - The exact number of votes available [depends on your voting behavior for the day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90202/). Concretely, there are three upper limits to respect *at the same time* to be able to vote.
>
>   - 40 post votes per day per user.
>   - 30 answer votes per day per user.
>   - 5 post votes after you got your first "5 votes remaining" warning of the day. If you reach 25 answer votes at time `t` of the day, given `q(t)` as the number of question votes cast by time `t`, the total post votes limit will be no more than `30 + q(t)`. If you cast less than 25 answer votes, ignore this point.
>
> So, basically, you get 10 votes *specifically for questions*, but you need to use them early.  Once you get close to the limit of 30 *unrestricted* votes, you can't claim all 10 of the others any more.
>
> No, I don't know why.  I suspect it's a limitation in how voting was implemented (the 10 extra votes for questions were a later addition), rather than an intentional design decision.

This behaviour has nothing to do with the UTC time.

---

For badge hunters: Use all your votes on questions to get the badge. And keep an eye on [Electorate](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/44/electorate):

> Vote on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions.

Voting on questions is important and these badges aim to encourage this behaviour.

Comment: Won't let me do anything with votes as far as I can tell, ah I think I must have exceeded the votes before warning bit.

Comment: @Ash You should have been warned about your daily usage. It always starts with "You have 5 votes left for the day". It may take a moment for the box to appear. And the message I cited first only appears when you have been using all your votes on answers for a day or two. A little tip for you badge hunter: there is another badge where you need to have 25% of all your votes on questions.

Comment: Aggravatingly enough I ran out on a Question vate too.

Comment: @Ash As has been explained in the linked post there is a time limit for voting on these questions. `So, basically, you get 10 votes specifically for questions, but you need to use them early. Once you get close to the limit of 30 unrestricted votes, you can't claim all 10 of the others any more.` Just try it tomorrow and focus on questions first if you want the badge

Comment: Not that worried about the badge really but since I was close anyway...

Comment: @Ash To answer the question you asked in the comment before deleting your question together with my answer: There is a difference between WorldBuilding Meta (which is basically *here*) and [Meta StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), which is a whole SE-site dedicated to governing SE. It's the only Meta site with reputation and it has a lot of interesting information about why things are as they are network wide. There are [similar proposals](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100705/352819) to yours but they don't come up here, because it's a different site.

Comment: Every time I thing I have a handle on the overall structure of this page... Working on putting the salient bit back up as a new question.

Comment: @Ash I don't quite get what you are trying to say. If you have any questions about the site or the network in general feel free to come to the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/the-factory-floor). There's not much going on right now. In a few hours most American regular chat users will probably come online.

Comment: While I thank you for the suggestion I can't even manage to post a basic comment on the chat boards so... yeah.

Comment: @Ash Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65179/discussion-between-secespitus-and-ash).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you need to **vote more on questions.**

See [Vote Up privilege](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) in the help center.

You get 30 votes per day to use as you please, plus 10 per day that are reserved specifically for questions. In order to meet the criteria for [Vox Populi](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/71/vox-populi) (vote 40 times in a day) you need to use all of your question-specific votes as well.