# Why do I have so few votes?

Tags: support, voting

I remember that the site lets you vote about 40 times over the course of a day.

Today I logged in, voted the answers on this [question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/110152/living-biological-boats-jasconius/110205#110205), about 9 votes and just a few more later... probably less than 15 votes. Then the site said I had to wait about 11 hours to vote again.

Why is it? Does the site consider my votes as spam?

Comment: See also [I only seem to have 32 votes a day](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3688/29)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at [your profile](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/48632/ekaen?tab=topactivity) shows that you have voted 34 times today as of writing this. You can see this in the lower right hand corner on the desktop version.

The thing about votes is that you don't necessarily always have 40 votes. To cite for example [Daily vote limit reached on 37 votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/113513/352819):

> There is a [limit of 30 all-purpose votes per day and 10 question-only votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/what-are-the-limits-on-how-i-can-cast-change-and-retract-votes).
>
> The tricky part is that you have to spend your questions-only votes first.

There are special votes that can only be used to upvote questions and these have to be used first if you want to have a total of 40 votes on any day.

Other than that you might be in a different timezone making your personal day different from the UTC day so that what you define as "yesterday evening" could still be counting for "today".

---

But in this specific case you just have used up all your general-purpose votes today and as you upvoted mainly answers you don't have the full amount of 10 question upvotes for today. Today your maximum seems to be 34.

Comment: you might be in a different timezone making your personal day different from the UTC day so that what you define as "yesterday evening" could still be counting for "today".                                                                                    Didn't think about that, but makes sense now.

Comment: Huh, I never knew about the question only votes... That's useful information to have.

Comment: @AndyD273 Not much of a badge hunter? Many people come across it when trying to obtain the Vox Populi badge and not having the ability to use 40 votes on the first day they are trying. See [Can't have the “Vox Populi” badge](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2789/cant-have-the-vox-populi-badge?rq=1) for example.

Comment: @Secespitus I kinda try for the badges, but not as much as some people I guess. I had noticed I couldn't get 40 when I tried for vox populi once, but figured it was a time zone problem or something and let it go. Now that I know maybe I'll try again.